# Method for removing tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

In case two synonymed tags end up becoming unrelated (e.g. through separating software development, etc), what would the proper method be for removing said synonym? I am asking for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start a post here suggesting it. If the mods agree, we nuke the link between the two tags.